# Disable google maps tile fading or detect if map is fully rendered?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, javafx

**Question**

Is there a way to disable the fading of google maps tiles? Or is there a way to detect if a map is fully rendered?

**Problem**

I'd like to get an event when a map is fully loaded (and rendered) and take a screenshot. I tried these events as suggested in several answers

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function(){
  // screenshot
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(){
  // screenshot
});

window.onload = function(e){
  // screenshot
};
```

but the tiles are still fading, even after all is loaded and the above mentioned events fired.

It looks like this: left is google maps, right is an automated screenshot that is taken after the events fired:

[image]

**Code**

The code is in html and JavaFX

demo.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    #mapcanvas {
      /* height: 4000px; we need the value from java */
      width: 100%
    }
    </style>


</head>
<body>
<div id="mapcanvas"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

        console.log("Loading map tiles");

        // set map canvas height
        document.getElementById('mapcanvas').style.height = window.mapCanvasHeight;

        document.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"));

        // the global window object is used to set variables via java
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(window.lat, window.lon);

        // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en
        var Options = {
            zoom: 17,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), Options);
        document.goToLocation = function(x, y) {

            console.log("goToLocation, lat: " + x +", lon:" + y);

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
            map.setCenter(latLng);

        }

        // this doesn't work properly because some tiles fade in and hence you get a snapshot with faded tiles
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function(){

            console.log("tilesloaded");

            java.onMapLoadingFinished();

        });

        // This event is fired when the map becomes idle after panning or zooming.
        // it works after all tiles were first loaded and you zoom afterwards ( but doesn't work a 100% all the time )
        // initially you still get faded tiles
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(){

            console.log("idle");

            // java.onMapLoadingFinished();

        });

        window.onload = function(e){

            console.log("window.onload");

            // java.onMapLoadingFinished();

        };

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

GoogleApp.java

```
import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

/**
 * Load google maps map and take a snapshot from it
 */
public class GoogleApp extends Application {

    // initial lat/lon
    double lat = 38.897676;
    double lon = -77.036483;

    double browserWidth = 1024; // this is set to 100% in the html css for the map canvas
    double browserHeight = 8000; // this is used in the html map canvas; IMPORTANT: when the app freezes during zoom in, then the problem is probably the height; it works without problems with height of e. g. 360

    MyBrowser webBrowser;
    TextField latitudeTextField;
    TextField longitudeTextField;

    private ScrollPane snapshotScrollPane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        webBrowser = new MyBrowser(browserWidth, browserHeight);

        ScrollPane browserScrollPane = new ScrollPane(webBrowser);
        snapshotScrollPane = new ScrollPane();

        SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane(browserScrollPane, snapshotScrollPane);

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(splitPane);
        borderPane.setRight(snapshotScrollPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 1024, 768);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    private void createSnapshot() {

        SnapshotParameters parameters = new SnapshotParameters();
        parameters.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        // new image from clipped image
        WritableImage wim = null;
        wim = webBrowser.snapshot(parameters, wim);

        snapshotScrollPane.setContent(new ImageView(wim));
    }

    public class JavaBridge {

        public void onMapLoadingFinished() {

            System.out.println("[javascript] onMapLoadingFinished");

            createSnapshot();

        }

        public void log(String text) {
            System.out.println("[javascript] " + text);
        }

    }

    private class MyBrowser extends Pane {

        WebView webView;
        WebEngine webEngine;

        public MyBrowser(double width, double height) {

            webView = new WebView();
            webView.setPrefWidth(width);
            webView.setPrefHeight(height);

            webEngine = webView.getEngine();

            webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<State>) (observable, oldState, newState) -> {

                System.out.println("[State] " + observable);

                if (newState == State.SCHEDULED) {

                    System.out.println("Webpage loaded");

                    // inject "java" object
                    JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                    JavaBridge bridge = new JavaBridge();
                    window.setMember("java", bridge);

                    // console.log
                    webEngine.executeScript("console.log = function(message)\n" + "{\n" + "    java.log(message);\n" + "};");

                    // initialize variables

                    // canvas height
                    webEngine.executeScript("window.mapCanvasHeight = '" + browserHeight + "px'");

                    System.out.println("Latitude = " + lat + ", Longitude = " + lon);

                    webEngine.executeScript("window.lat = " + lat + ";" + "window.lon = " + lon + ";");

                }

                if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    // createSnapshot();
                }
            });

            // logging other properties
            webEngine.getLoadWorker().exceptionProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Throwable>) (ov, t, t1) -> System.out.println("[Exception] " + t1.getMessage()));
            webEngine.getLoadWorker().progressProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldState, newState) -> System.out.println( "[Progress] " + newState));
            webEngine.getLoadWorker().workDoneProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldState, newState) -> System.out.println( "[WorkDone] " + newState));
            webEngine.getLoadWorker().runningProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Boolean>) (observable, oldState, newState) -> System.out.println( "[Running] " + newState));
            webEngine.getLoadWorker().messageProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<String>) (observable, oldState, newState) -> System.out.println( "[Message] " + newState));


            final URL urlGoogleMaps = getClass().getResource("demo.html");
            webEngine.load(urlGoogleMaps.toExternalForm());

            // TODO: how should that work? it doesn't do anything when we invoke an alert
            webEngine.setOnAlert(e -> System.out.println("Alert: " + e.toString()));

            getChildren().add(webView);

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

console output

```
[WorkDone] 0.0
[Progress] 0.0
[State] ReadOnlyObjectProperty [bean: javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker@6954b271, name: state, value: SCHEDULED]
Webpage loaded
Latitude = 38.897676, Longitude = -77.036483
[Running] true
[State] ReadOnlyObjectProperty [bean: javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker@6954b271, name: state, value: RUNNING]
[WorkDone] 50.0
[Progress] 0.5
[WorkDone] 66.66666666666667
[Progress] 0.6666666666666667
[WorkDone] 76.59016927083334
[Progress] 0.7659016927083334
[javascript] Loading map tiles
[WorkDone] 79.69424280262338
[Progress] 0.7969424280262337
[WorkDone] 82.91479192680356
[Progress] 0.8291479192680357
[WorkDone] 86.13534105098375
[Progress] 0.8613534105098376
[WorkDone] 87.9566062307981
[Progress] 0.879566062307981
[WorkDone] 89.554165026828
[Progress] 0.89554165026828
[WorkDone] 89.62836770069038
[Progress] 0.8962836770069037
[javascript] idle
[WorkDone] 89.70492380394815
[Progress] 0.8970492380394814
[WorkDone] 89.78964107398804
[Progress] 0.8978964107398804
[WorkDone] 89.85311355504936
[Progress] 0.8985311355504936
[WorkDone] 89.91528395017954
[Progress] 0.8991528395017955
[WorkDone] 89.9528416875862
[Progress] 0.899528416875862
[javascript] window.onload
[Message] Loading complete
[WorkDone] 100.0
[Progress] 1.0
[State] ReadOnlyObjectProperty [bean: javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker@6954b271, name: state, value: SUCCEEDED]
[Running] false
[javascript] tilesloaded
[javascript] onMapLoadingFinished
taking screenshot
```

Of course one could wait a second and take the screenshot then, but that's not a proper solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The google maps events are tied very individually. The `tilesloaded` listener particularly fires even while the map may be panning. This can be seen by trying to stress the map in this listeners example [here](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/map_events/map_events.html)

Additionally, the `idle` listener gets fired several times during a pan. It may be best to place a timer with a set amount of time that would determine that the user has completely stopped panning/zooming and then take the screenshot. Here's a basic example:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
    var mapMoveTimer, tileLoadedListener;
    var moveDetect = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", function () {
        clearTimeout(mapMoveTimer);
    });

    mapMoveTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        google.maps.event.removeListener(moveDetect);

        // here is your code
        tileLoadedListener = google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function(){
            console.log("tilesloaded");
            java.onMapLoadingFinished();

            // make sure to remove the listener so it isn't fired multiple times.
            google.maps.event.removeListener(tileLoadedListener);
        });
    });

    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but as stated in the question I'd like to have a proper solution and not a guess when the map may be fully loaded and rendered. A timer is not an option.

Comment: This is the solution I have to go with, since there doesn't seem to be a proper one. I figured that a timeout of 200ms is sufficient. Note: In the google api source there is a property "tileFadeMode", but there's no description about it and the code is obfuscated.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't been able to find a way to determine when the map is fully loaded, but you can get the map as an image in the first place, using the google maps static api  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro.

Here is a code snippet that loads a static map:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="staticView" style="width:400px; height:400px"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var mapImage = new Image();
    var eltStaticView = $("#staticView");
    $(mapImage).one('load', function() {
      eltStaticView.css('background-image', 'url(' + mapImage.src + ')');
      console.log("Image Has Loaded");
      $(mapImage).unbind();
    });
    $(mapImage).error(function() {
      $(mapImage).unbind();
    });
    var imageSrc =  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&zoom=12&size=400x400&maptype=satellite"; //+ "&key=" + YOUR_API_KEY
    mapImage.src = imageSrc;
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But unfortunately that's limited to a 640x640 resolution.

Comment: @Roland, Yes, unless you have a premium account.  I started using that method when I was looking for a notification when Streetview had finished loading.  At that time there was no resolution limit.  I did an extensive search of SO, and all answers indicated that there is no event fired when the tiles finish loading.

Comment: Yes, but even with a premium account it would be only 2048x2048.

Answer (score 2):

What Google map API version you are using?

You can check with "tilesloaded" event.

Also there is an event called as "idle" which will be called once your map is in idle condition.

The "idle" event is called when the map goes to idle state - everything loaded completely or something wrong has happened and map failed to load.
I think "idle" is more reliable then tilesloaded/bounds_changed and using addListenerOnce method the code in the closure is executed the first time "idle" is fired and then the event is detached.

Check description about above events at [Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you, but as stated in the question I already tried these. API version is 3.

Comment: This can be due to you Internet speed or browser performance. Can you post any video of how does it load or if you can provide any code?

Comment: I added the code, it's in JavaFX. Don't know if you can make use of that. Anyway, thanks for helping :-) The internet speed shouldn't be an issue. The event must only fire when all is finished. My guess is that some javascript fading is still running concurrently while the tilesloaded or idle events are fired.